# Drupal 6 node_load with conditions

Tags: 6, nodes, database

Here is the situation:

I have two content types. Content type a has a CCK reference field for content type b.

Now I am trying to load all the nodes from content type a that are referenced to content type b.

Here is the code that I have.

```
$nidcur =  $fields['nid']->content;

$node = node_load(array("field_micselect" => $nidcur));

dpm($node);
```

So I would like to load all the nodes that are related to the nid $nidcur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$referenced_nodes = db_query("SELECT `field_FIELD_NAME_nid` AS `nid` FROM {content_field_FIELD_NAME}");
while ($referenced_node = db_fetch_object($referenced_nodes)) {
  $node = node_load(array('nid' => $referenced_node->nid));
  // Do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: It worked. thank you very much. Here is the code again. I added the posibility to tell which nid you are looking for. Hopefully it helps somebody ;)    
     
      $nidcur =  $fields['nid']->content;

       $referenced_nodes = db_query("SELECT `field_FIELD_NAME_nid` AS `nid` FROM {content_field_FIELD_NAME} WHERE field_NAME_nid = " . $nidcur);
      while ($referenced_node = db_fetch_object($referenced_nodes)) {
        $node = node_load(array('nid' => $referenced_node->nid));
 
       }